# std::vector erase issue with MSVC 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, vector, std, erase

ALL,

I have a class defined that just holds the data (different types of data). I also have std::vector that holds a pointers to objects of this class.

Something like this:

```
class Foo
{
};

class Bar
{
private:
    std::vector<Foo *> m_fooVector;
};
```

At one point of time in my program I want to remove an element from this vector. And so I write following:

```
for (std::vector<Foo *>::iterator it = m_fooVector.begin(); it <= m_fooVector.end(); )
{
    if( checking it condition is true )
    {
        delete (*it);
        (*it) = NULL;
        m_fooVector.erase( it );
    }
}
```

The problem is that the erase operation fails. When I open the debugger I still see this element inside the vector and when the program finishes it crashes because the element is half way here.

In another function I am trying to remove the simple std::wstring from the vector and everything works fine - string is removed and the size of the vector decreased.

What could be the problem for such behavior? I could of course try to check the erase function in MSVC standard library, but I don't even know where to start.

TIA!!!

Comment: I believe MSVC 2010 supported C++11's `std::unique_ptr`. You may be able to put it to use and simplify some of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for (std::vector<Foo *>::iterator it = m_fooVector.begin(); it != m_fooVector.end(); )
{
    if (/*checking it condition is true*/)
    {
        delete *it;
        // *it = NULL; // Not needed
        it = m_fooVector.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Traditional way is [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), but as you have to call `delete` first (smart pointer would avoid this issue), you might use `std::partition` instead of `std::remove`:

```
auto it = std::partition(m_fooVector.begin(), m_fooVector.end(), ShouldBeKeptFunc);
for (std::vector<Foo *>::iterator it = m_fooVector.begin(); it != m_fooVector.end(); ++it) {
    delete *it;
}
m_fooVector.erase(it, m_fooVector.end());
```

Comment: just curious - how it will look like with unique_ptr? std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo()> >? Or I am wrong with the syntax? Also is MSVC 2010 fully support this type of pointer? I will try to correct the code when I get home...

Comment: Without the extra parenthesis: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo> >`. Unsure of the support of MSVC 2010 to propose it as solution.